# Are variables created in the except: stage available in the finally: stage?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, try-catch-finally

I have a `try/except*n/finally` block of code and I was wondering what the correct way to do the following is:

```
try:
    some_function()
except exceptions.ExceptionA as e:
    self.logger.error("Error")
    subject = 'error A'
    message = 'Check error A'
except exceptions.ExceptionB as b:
    self.logger.error("Error")
    subject = 'error A'
    message = 'Check error A'
finally:
    self.publish(subject, message)
    sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 2):

No, because `finally` is executed *always*, not just when an exception has been raised and handled. It'll be executed when there is no exception, or an exception was raised you do not handle, or you used `return` or used `continue` or `break` in a loop outside the `try`, etc.

**If** an exception has been handled, then names you bind in an `except` suite will remain set by the time the `finally` suite executes, but you need to set them to sentinel values first lest you want to avoid `NameError` or `UnboundLocal` exceptions in case no such exception was raised:

```
subject = message = None
try:
    some_function()
except exceptions.ExceptionA as e:
    self.logger.error("Error")
    subject = 'error A'
    message = 'Check error A'
except exceptions.ExceptionB as b:
    self.logger.error("Error")
    subject = 'error A'
    message = 'Check error A'
finally:
    # message and subject *can* be bound to None now
    self.publish(subject, message)
    sys.exit()
```

If you wanted to execute code *only* if an exception was raised and handled, you'll have to do so explicitly for each `except` suite. You cannot use `finally` for that case, not without additional checking (you could gate on `subject is not None` for example).

Comment: Ah yes, for some reason I forgot that finally is called even when there is no exception called! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use variables from `except` in `finally` blocks because variables in Python have function scope.

```
In [1]: try:
   ...:     raise ValueError()
   ...: except:
   ...:     x = 1
   ...: finally:
   ...:     print(x)
   ...:     
1
```

But you have to make sure the variable is initialized in all code paths.

```
try:
    pass
except:
    x = 1
finally:
    print(x) # NameError
```

Typically, you will initialize the variables first:

```
x = None
try:
    ...
except:
    x = ...
finally:
    ... safe to use x here ...
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I appreciate the thought, but you've just translated one piece of code you can't run into one other piece of code you can't run.  I prefer the ellipses to comments, because the comments don't work in Python.